# Grab Selected Text Using SendMessage and GETSELTEXT

Tags: vb.net, text, get, selected

Using SendMessage (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SendMessage.html) + WM_GETSELTEXT how could I grab the currently selected text in VB.NET?

Comment: are you looking to port this code to vb.net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333684/cricheditctrlgetseltext-is-not-working-right

Comment: Yes, apart from I need the selected text of the current active window.